# Android Intent Switching Crashes onClick

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm fairly confused with this one. In my MainActivity.java I have a button that's supposed to go over to another class in another file `RedGreenTest.java`

```
redButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        findViewById(R.id.testRG_button);
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RedGreenTest.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

So the button gets clicked, and bam insta-crash. Debugger tells me that it's `startActivity(i);` no dua. Going into the manifest, I change my `<activity android:name=".MainActivity">` to `<activity android:name=".RedGreenTest">` and the app starts up just fine.

Here is the beginning of my onCreate() class from the `MainActivity.java` file:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_select_layout);
...
```

And my onCreate() in my `RedGreenTest.java`:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.red_green_layout);
...
```

Running this through the debugger, I'm not getting any errors when the `RedGreenTest.java` file is set in the Manifest.

What fundamental am I just missing from this what-should-be simple intent switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have both activities added to the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".RedGreenTest">
  ...
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

The reason that the app starts when you change MainActivity to RedGreenTest, is because you are setting the RedGreenTest activity to be the launch activity, which is set by the intent filter.

Comment: Christ, that is painfully simple.... Fixed it perfectly. I feel like a real div now. Thank you so much for this.
My professor never taught us that you can have more than one in the Manifest. In fact, he hasn't taught us really anything other than how to use Android Studio.

Comment: Lol... Sorry to hear that. But you were right that it was a fundamental issue. For the record, you need to add each activity to the manifest. You can do some cool stuff with intent filters, broadcast receivers, and more. Check it out. The manifest is used for quite a bit of stuff. Good luck with everything else.